# Derivative of dot product of two matrices with respect to another matrix?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

[image]

This is from one of the questions on stackexchange. 
However, I would like to extend this to the following:

[image]

Can someone disprove/prove it and give me references to why it is true/untrue?

Any resources that would help me resolve/understand this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is $\frac{\partial {s}}{\partial z}$ the Jacobian Matrix?

Comment: Yes, it is. I think the extension is correct. Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: Yes, you mean that $r$ and $s$ depend on more than one variable. By writing out the Jacobian, you can apply (1.9) in each column (since the partial deriv. with respect to a specific variable is essentially holding all other variables constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At real calculus, we say that a function $f:A\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x_{0}\in A$ if the limit $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$If the limit exists, we define the derivative of f at a, $f'(a)$ by its value.

Generally, we say that a function $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is differentiable at $a\in U$ if there is a matrix B, $m\times n$ satisfying $$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-B\cdot h}{|h|} \rightarrow 0$$ when $|h|\rightarrow 0$. So, $B$ is the derivative of $f$ at $a$. Writting the usual notation, $B=Df(a)$. You can prove the dot product generally.

By the way, writting $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by $\vec{x}=(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})$ and $f=(f_{1},\dots,f_{m}),$
$$Df(\vec{x})=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}} \dots \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{n}} \\
\,\,\,\,\vdots\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{1}} \dots \frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{n}}
\end{array}\right] $$.

Let $k\leq n$ an integer and $\vec{z}\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$. We can write $\vec{x}=(\vec{z},\vec{w})$, where $\vec{w}\in\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$. So, 
$$Df(\vec{x})=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial \vec{z}}\,\,\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial \vec{w}} \\
\,\,\,\,\vdots\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial \vec{z}}\,\,\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial \vec{w}}
\end{array}\right] $$.

Thinking that way you are able to solve your problem